# How to find out if key exists or not when parsing json data

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am trying to parse json file using Java.My json file format is given below.I was trying to print a message if the action is a "note" and print performed_at. However,there is no output for the below code.

Thanks in advance for the advice and your time.Appreciate it.

```
 {
"data": {
    "name": "John"

},
"activities_data": [{
        "performed_at": "April",
        "id": 630,

        "action": {
            "address": "N/A",

            "issue_type": "F A"

        }
    },
    {
        "performed_at": "March",
        "id": 687,

        "action": {
            "note": {
                "id": 26519,
                "type": 4
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Java code:

```
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
    import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
    import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Map; 


    public class Readjsonfile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject ticketObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader("activity.json"));




        JSONArray jsonArray= (JSONArray) ticketObject.get("activities_data");


        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++){

            Map activityobject  = ((Map)jsonArray.get(i));
            System.out.println(activityobject);
            if (activityobject.containsKey("note"))
                {  
                System.out.println("its a note");
                    \\and print performed_at here
                }
            }   

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your JSON is incorrect, and has no proper format... The least you could do asking for help is posting a proper JSON, using for example a prettifier like this one: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @thelawnmowerman Sorry for that..I have corrected my mistake

Comment: The JSON info is still wrong, use the checker I've linked above, and you will find at least 4 errors in it.

Comment: OK, now it parses :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should nest a level deeper to get the note.

```
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++){
    Map activityobject  = ((Map)jsonArray.get(i));
    System.out.println(activityobject);
    if (activityobject.containsKey("action")) {
        Map actionObject  = ((Map)activityobject.get("action"));
        if (actionObject.containsKey("note")) {
            System.out.println("its a note");
            System.out.println("note" + actionObject.get("note"));
            System.out.println("Performed at " + activityobject.get("performed_at"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
{"performed_at":"April","action":{"address":"N\/A","issue_type":"F A"},"id":630}
{"performed_at":"March","action":{"note":{"id":26519,"type":4}},"id":687}
its a note
note{"id":26519,"type":4}
Performed at March
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get a `JsonObject`, not a `Map`:

```
JSONObject activityobject  = ((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
```

And then you have to load the `action` part of the JSON (you can't look for an attribute recursively:

```
JSONObject actionObject  = ((JSONObject) activityobject.get('action'));
```

And finally you should use `has()` to check for the attribute you want:

```
if (actionObject.has('note')) {
```